# Arabic numbers for theorem, Roman numbers for \phantomsection in theorem

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, roman-numerals

I use Roman numbers for chapters and sections, and Arabic numbers for theorems.

When I want to refer to `\phantomsection` in the theorem, I find that the reference turns back to an Arabic number. How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Roman{section}}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{A}
    \section{A}
    \begin{theorem}
        asdf asdf asd asd asd fasd asd asdf asd asd asd asd a sdfas dsa  as dfasd as dfas df asd a dfsda \phantomsection\label{LABEL}$Ax=b$.
    \end{theorem}
    I want \ref{LABEL} to be \thesection. Could not understand why redefining \textbackslash thetheorem affects \textbackslash thesection.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `\phantomsection`? Pul differently, why don't you issue two `\label` instructions -- one to be associated with the section (no `\phantomsection` needed) and the other with the `theorem` environment?

Comment: if you wanna `ref` the section you should put `\label`after the `\section{A}` otherwise you you will `ref` the theorem

Comment: @Mico Actually I want to refer to inline formula, that is, when I click the hyperlink pdf will jump to the exact line of that formula.

Comment: Please modify your sample code so that it relates to what you're really looking to achieve. (Hint: the solution will not involve `\phantomsection`.)

Comment: What it does right now is refer to inline formula. So you wanna it display in Roman as well?

Comment: @Tom Yes exactly

Comment: @Mico Do you mean this?

Comment: @Tom -- Sorry, but `\label{LABEL}` currently does *not* "point at" the inline formula `$Ax=b$`. Instead, LaTeX associates `LABEL` with the `theorem` counter, since that's the counter that was most recently incremented via a `\refstepcounter` directive. `\phantomsection` will not help the OP here.

Comment: @Mico Oh I just not sure if my modification meets your need. Look forward to your solution.

Comment: Move the label behind the theorem environment, but leave the phantomsection inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\label` generally refers to the last counter to which `\refstepcounter` has been applied *in the same scope*.

Issuing `\label` far away from the place where a counter has been “refstepped” is usually not advised, because the reference is unpredictable.

The command `\phantomsection` has actually nothing to do with sections. Its name has been chosen because its most common usage is for emulating the presence of a sectional command, but it just sets an anchor for a hyperlink.

I suggest defining your special labeling command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Roman{section}}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\seclabel}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname
  \begingroup
  \let\@bsphack\relax\let\@esphack\relax % we don't want them here
  \edef\@currentlabel{\thesection}%
  \label{#1}%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

\section{A}

\begin{theorem}
asdf asdf asd asd asd fasd asd asdf asd asd asd asd a sdfas dsa  
as dfasd as dfas df asd a dfsda \seclabel{LABEL}$Ax=b$.
\end{theorem}

I want \ref{LABEL} to be \thesection. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have question is `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` mandatory here?

Comment: @Tom Yes, if you want to fully emulate the behavior of `\label`.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that your real objective is to make a given inline formula into a hypertarget, so that readers can "jump" to that formula from elsewhere in the document by "clicking" on a suitably constructed hyperlink elsewhere in the document.

If that's the case, the `\phantomsection` directive isn't a tool suitable for the job. Instead, do look into the `\hypertarget` and `\hyperref` macros that are provided by the `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. 
    Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time.
    \hypertarget{emc2}{$E=mc^2$}.
    Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time.
    Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time.
    
    \bigskip\noindent
    Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. 
    Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time.
    \hyperlink{emc2}{An inline formula}.
    Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time.
    Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time. Once upon a time.
\end{document}
```

Note that first arguments of `\hypertarget` and `hyperref` have to the same.

Do also observe that the inline formula is *not* associated meaningfully with an equation number, or with any other counter variable for that matter.

Comment: Thank you! It does work as a manual approach, but I do want something more: I want the \hyperlink automatically gives a link with the section as the link text, which is in Roman style. For example, in my MWE I want a link to the inline formula with text `I.I'

Comment: @JRen - I'm afraid that your objective cannot be achieved in a fully automated way, as LaTeX does not provide the means to associate a given link (whether created by  `\label` or by `\hypertarget`) with the current section number.

Comment: Sounds hopeless... Thanks anyway, I'll keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: I can't test now, but this sounds wrong, phantomsection should be fine to create a link target.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - It's possible I never understood the OP's actual objective.

Answer (score 1):

\phantomsection has nothing to do with a section, it only sets an anonymous anchor. The printed layout of your label depends only on the position of the `\label`.

You can get your wanted output by moving the `\label` behind the theorem environment:

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Roman{section}}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{A}
    \section{A}
    \begin{theorem}
        asdf asdf asd asd asd fasd asd asdf asd asd asd asd a sdfas dsa  as dfasd as dfas df asd a dfsda \phantomsection$Ax=b$.
    \end{theorem}\label{LABEL}
    I want \ref{LABEL} to be \thesection. Could not understand why redefining \textbackslash thetheorem affects \textbackslash thesection.
\end{document}
```

But more safer is to use two labels, one for the number and one for the anchor:

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Roman{section}}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{A}
    \section{A}\label{section}
    \begin{theorem}
        asdf asdf asd asd asd fasd asd asdf asd asd asd asd a sdfas dsa  as dfasd as dfas df asd a dfsda \phantomsection\label{position}$Ax=b$.
    \end{theorem}
    I want \hyperref[position]{\ref*{section}} to be \thesection. Could not understand why redefining \textbackslash thetheorem affects \textbackslash thesection.
\end{document}
```